# R - How to extract the time from a datetime column to use for graphing

Tags: r, datetime, time, col

I have a column named time that contains the date and time, listed in this format ex: `03/20/2016 14:24:47.153`. I want to extract the time portion to be used to produce a line graph (so I will like a comprehensive x axis time interval). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract the "time" from the string.

```
sub("\\S+\\s+", "", str1)
#[1] "14:24:47.153"
```

---

Or convert to Datetime class and then `format`

```
options(digits.secs=3)
format(strptime(str1, format= "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS"), "%H:%M:%OS3")
#[1] "14:24:47.153"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "03/20/2016 14:24:47.153"
```